# unable to create a windows 7, bootable usb flash drive

Tags: 14.04

I am really screwed up by trying making bootable usb stick using unetbootin and winusb
In unetbootin when i restart my pc a windows shows unetbootin is booting in 10 sec automatically and then after reaching 1 the countdown starts again.
And in winusb when i restart my pc it boots automatically in existing ubuntu 14.04
I made perfect bootable usb disk both time

Answer (score -1):

You need to choose boot device (press F7 or other during boot).

Comment: In my pc boot manager opens by pressing f12. I did it 1000s of times but still when i create bootable usb driver via unetbootin it doesnt work and via winusb, after pressing f12 selecting usb hdd it boot back into ubuntu